# Number of DB connections opened

Tags: mysql

Can anyone know the way to get the number of DB connection being used , in MYSQL 5.0

Answer (score 24):

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name = 'Threads_connected'
```

Answer (score 3):

[12.5.5.31. SHOW PROCESSLIST Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html)

Shows you how many people are connected to the server.

Comment: Actually, i need to know how many DB connections have been opened so far

Comment: In That case you can use:
    SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name = 'Threads_created';

And to see the maximum connections opened at any one time use

    SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name = 'Max_used_connections';

Answer (score 3):

```
Number of open connections can be found out by using below query:
   mysql -e 'SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE "Threads_%" OR variable_name = "Connections"'

   +-------------------+-------+
   | Variable_name     | Value |
   +-------------------+-------+
   | Connections       | 862   |
   | Threads_cached    | 0     |
   | Threads_connected | 10    |
   | Threads_created   | 26    |
   | Threads_running   | 1     |
   +-------------------+-------+
```