# MySQL show status - active or total connections?

Tags: mysql, connection

When I run `show status like 'Con%'` it shows the number of connections, which is 9972 and constantly growing. Is this an active number of connections or connections made in total?

Answer (score 587):

According to [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections), it means the total number throughout history:

> **`Connections`**
>
> The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server.

You can see the number of *active* connections either through the [`Threads_connected`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Threads_connected) status variable:

> **`Threads_connected`**
>
> The number of currently open connections.

```
mysql> show status where `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| Threads_connected | 4     |
+-------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

... or through the `show processlist` command:

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host            | db     | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+----+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
|  3 | root | localhost       | webapp | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist | 
|  5 | root | localhost:61704 | webapp | Sleep   |  208 |       | NULL             | 
|  6 | root | localhost:61705 | webapp | Sleep   |  208 |       | NULL             | 
|  7 | root | localhost:61706 | webapp | Sleep   |  208 |       | NULL             | 
+----+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Does a connection represent a user? So if there are 200 users on a page that makes database queries will be 200 connections?

Comment: Yes, can someone clarify it. I too have same question. Also, does these variables reset after every MySQL Services restart or after Server reboot ?

Comment: @Diego Queiroz It's not that simple. If the developer both paid close attention and if there's only 1 database that needs to be connected to per user, then yes, each of these will be a user. But it's possible there are other utilities running or backup services that will also need to connect.

Comment: @LonelyRogue Yes, after the server restarts, every connection needs to reconnect. Many programs/libraries will auto-connect so the # of connections might fill up quickly without explicitly doing anything. But MySQL won't keep any old connections after a restart.

Comment: mysql -e "SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';"
-bash: variable_name: command not found
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'Threads_connected'' at line 1

Answer (score 166):

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

This will show you all the open connections.

Comment: mysql -e "SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';"
-bash: variable_name: command not found
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'Threads_connected'' at line 1

Answer (score 36):

You can also do

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Max_used_connections';
```

Comment: `max_used_connections` is also useful

Comment: Shouldn't max_user_connections [refer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections) to the maximum number of user allowed to connect to the database at the same time? This reports the fixed variable of mysql, not an actual operative value.

Answer (score 27):

This is the total number of connections to the server till now. 
To find current conection status you can use

> mysqladmin -u  -p extended-status | grep -wi
>   'threads_connected\|threads_running' | awk '{ print $2,$4}'

This will show you:

```
Threads_connected 12

Threads_running 1  

Threads_connected: Number of connections

Threads_running: connections currently running some sql
```

Answer (score 23):

To see a more complete list you can run:

```
show session status;
```

or

```
show global status;
```

See [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html) to better understand the usage.

If you want to know details about the database you can run:

```
status;
```

Answer (score 10):

In order to check the maximum allowed connections, you can run the following query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
```

To check the number of active connections, you can run the following query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_used_connections";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_used_connections";` returned `Empty set (0.00 sec)` but 
    SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Max_used_connections'; with "`" around "variable_name" worked

Comment: `SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name = "max_used_connections";`

Comment: max_used_connections shows the maximum number of connections used since the database started not the current active connections. Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Max_used_connections

Answer (score 2):

As per doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections

Connections

The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server.

Answer (score 1):

## A GUI solutions of MySQL queries:

If someone wants to show all active connection without any MySQL code, then you can use [Session Manager in dbForge Studio](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/show-running-queries-in-processlist.html):

Simply, open <kbd>Database</kbd> > <kbd>Session Manager</kbd> in the upper menu, and you'll see all active connections:

[image]

It will do the same thing that is done by these [MySQL commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.1/en/show-processlist.html):

```
show full processlist;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST p;
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.threads t;
```

Answer (score -3):

It should be the current number of active connections. Run the command `processlist` to make sure.

URL for reference: http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/mysql/how-show-open-database-connections-mysql

EDIT: [Number of DB connections opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824428/number-of-db-connections-opened) Please take a look here, the actual number of threads (connections) are described here!

Comment: I've found the reference links useful. For example, `show status like '%onn%';` is a very useful query.

Comment: This answer is wrong and should be deleted. See the other answers.

Comment: From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections:
"The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server".
It is NOT the number of active connections.

Comment: All sorts of connect stats, Aborted_connects, Connections are cumulative.  Max_used_connections is the high water mark, Threads_connected is current, but show processlist gives id values as well as what is going on.