# mySQL Error 1040: Too Many Connection

Tags: mysql, connection

How to fix these, "SQL Error 1040: Too Many Connection"
even I try to put

```
max_user_connection=500
```

still "Too many connection"

Comment: Here's the only thing that worked in our case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226015/error-too-many-connections-on-codeigniter-website

Answer (score 90):

**MySQL: ERROR 1040: Too many connections**

This basically tells that MySQL handles the maximum number of connections simultaneously and by default it handles **100** connections simultaneously.

These following reasons cause MySQL to run out connections.

1. Slow Queries
2. Data Storage Techniques
3. Bad MySQL configuration

I was able to overcome this issues by doing the followings.

Open `MySQL command line tool` and type,

```
show variables like "max_connections";
```

This will return you something like this.

```
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 100   |
+-----------------+-------+
```

You can change the setting to e.g. 200 by issuing the following command without having to restart the MySQL server.

```
set global max_connections = 200;
```

Now when you restart MySQL the next time it will use this setting instead of the default.

***Keep in mind that increase of the number of connections will increase the amount of RAM required for MySQL to run.***

Comment: Just a note: new default max_connections is 151. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

Comment: hi, what if you have set max_connections in some configs somewhere in the filesystem; will this global set still dominate?

Comment: "Now when you restart MySQL the next time it will use this setting instead of the default."-- is this really the case?

Comment: @DingxinXu This fix was only temporary on my RHEL7 machine. I had to modify `/etc/my.cnf` to have `max_connections = 200` in order for the change to persist across MySQL restarts.

Answer (score 42):

It is worth knowing that if you run out of usable disc space on your server partition or drive, that this will also cause MySQL to return this error. If you're sure it's *not* the actual [number of users connected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42196994/3536236) then the next step is to check that you have free space on your MySQL server drive/partition.

*Edit January 2019:*
This is true of MySQL 5.7 and 5.8 . I do not know for versions above this.

Comment: The lack of free disk space causes MySQL to wait before an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` can complete, which in turn causes the number of pending user connections to increase until the limit is reached.

Answer (score 34):

If you are running out of connections like this, chances are excellent that you are not closing the connections that you have open.

Review code that opens connections and ensure the connections are closed as soon as practical.  Typically you want to make use of the *using* keyword around anything that implements *IDisposable* (including database connections) to ensure that such objects are disposed as soon as they leave the scope where they are needed.

You can check the current number of active connections with this query:

```
show processlist
```

Reference: [MySQL show status - active or total connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7432241/141172)

Comment: after all my codes at the end of the query I always close the connection... this error only appears when I open another computer or my program

Comment: but does it actually get closed? exceptions can cause close to be skipped

Comment: yes. when we used 2-20 computer it works properly but when we add 30 more error 1040 occur

Comment: In that case I agree with @SirRufo that the server-side connection limit is too low.  Try setting max_connections higher in my.ini/my.cnf.

Comment: If someone is going to downvote an answer nearly two years later, it would be helpful to me and the community at large to leave a reason for the downvote.

Comment: Thanks, this lead me right to the problem. An outsourced custom CMS never included a single instance of mysql_free_result() or mysql_close(). Hilarity ensues. I'm probably going to go cry in a corner instead of fixing all 1200 fetch instances.

Comment: @Imperative: Ouch, I feel for you.  Profile the application's SQL calls and fix the most common calls first :-)

Comment: The good news is that by sticking mysql_close() in the global footer, I was able to fake it. I decided not to bother with mysql_free_result() though, that would have taken hours. Not to mention I was writing deprecated code on an old non-PDO setup.

Comment: This answer is not for mysql

Comment: @baldrs: The question was retagged MySQL after I posted my answer.  Updated my answer to show an appropriate query for MySQL.

Answer (score 27):

This error occurs, due to connection limit reaches the maximum limit, defined in the configuration file `my.cnf`.

In order to fix this error, login to MySQL as `root` user (Note: you can login as root, since, mysql will pre-allocate additional one connection for `root user`) and increase the **max_connections** variable by using the following command:

```
SET GLOBAL max_connections = 500;
```

This change will be there, until next server restart. In order to make this change permanent, you have to modify in your configuration file. You can do this by,

```
vi /etc/my.cnf

[mysqld]
max_connections = 500
```

[This article](http://www.rathishkumar.com/2017/07/how-to-fix-mysql-too-many-connections.html) has detailed step by step [workaround to fix this error](http://www.rathishkumar.com/2017/07/how-to-fix-mysql-too-many-connections.html). Have a look at it, I hope it may help you. Thanks.

Comment: It is not always a good idea to increase number of connections as this will increase memory footprint. See also top voted answer where this is pointed out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42196994/2444812

Answer (score 9):

You have to change `max_connections` to increase total permitted connections.

And set `max_user_connections` back to default 0 => **no limit** unless you need to **limit** this per user connections.

[MySQL Too many connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html)

Comment: Any reason why no limit should be the best option?

Comment: It is the best option "unless you need to **limit** this per user connection" ;o)

Answer (score 8):

In your program you would have opened the connections and left open without closing it.

I faced a same problem and finally identified.

I added this code, after try catch.

```
finally{
    try {
        rs.close();
        p.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do this in a cleaner way with the `using` keyword.

Comment: @EricJ. FYI the above code snippet is in `java` and not `C#`.

Comment: should each close statement have it's own try-catch block? Also bad practice to just log, better to rethrow.

Answer (score 8):

To see how many connections are configured for your DB to use:

```
select @@max_connections;
```

To change it:

```
set global max_connections = 200;
```

To see how many are connected at the current time:

```
show processlist;
```

I also wrote [this piece of software](https://github.com/CherryCircle/MySQLSlowLogAnalyzer) to help me create a nice spreadsheet of transactions over time so I can track down which queries are the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

open the terminal and type this command : `sudo gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Paste the line in my.cnf file: `set-variable=max_connections=500`

Comment: Pasting the line resulted in this error: "mysql: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 22!
mysql: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
"

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error even though I had all my Connections wrapped in using statements.  The thing I was overlooking is how long those connections were staying open.

I was doing something like this:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    foreach(var m in conn.Query<model>(sql))
    {
        // do something that takes a while, accesses disk or even open up other connections
    }
}
```

Remember that connection will not close until everything in the loop is done and if the loop creates more connections, they can really start adding up.

This is better:

```
List<model> models = null;
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    models = conn.Query<model>(sql).ToList(); // to list is needed here since once the connection is closed you can't step through an IEnumerable   
}

foreach(var m in models)
{
    // do something that takes a while, accesses disk or even open up other connections
}
```

That way your connection is allowed to close and is released back to the connection pool before you go to do other things

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs mostly when the maximum allowed concurrent connections to MySQL has exceeded.
The max connections allowed is stored in the gloobal variable max_connections.
You can check it by `show global variables like max_connections;` in MySQL

You can fix it by the following steps:

**Step1:**

Login to MySQL and run this command: `SET GLOBAL max_connections = 100;`

Now login to MySQL, the too many connection error fixed. This method does not require server restart.

**Step2:**

Using the above step1 you can resolve ths issue but max_connections will roll back to its default value when mysql is restarted.

In order to make the max_connection value permanent, update the my.cnf file.

Stop the MySQL server:  `Service mysql stop`

Edit the configuration file my.cnf: `vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Find the variable max_connections under mysqld section.

`[mysql]`

`max_connections = 300`

Set into higher value and save the file.

Start the server: `Service mysql start`

**Note:**
Before increasing the max_connections variable value, make sure that, the server has adequate memory for new requests and connections.

MySQL pre-allocate memory for each connections and de-allocate only when the connection get closed. When new connections are querying, system should have enough resources such memory, network and computation power to satisfy the user requests.

Also, you should consider increasing the open tables limit in MySQL server to accommodate the additional request. And finally. it is very important to close the connections which are completed transaction on the server.

Answer (score 1):

> Before increasing the max_connections variable, you have to check how
> many non-interactive connection you have by running show processlist
> command.
>
> If you have many sleep connection, you have to decrease the value of
> the "wait_timeout" variable to close non-interactive connection after
> waiting some times.

https://serverfault.com/questions/281420/should-i-worry-about-mysql-sleep-status-process-in-processlist/959315#959315

Answer (score 0):

Check if your current running application is still accessing your mysql and has consumed all the DB connections.

So if you try to access mysql from workbench , you will get "too many connections" error.

stop your current running web application which is holding all those db connections and then your issue will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue noted clearly in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/too-many-connections.html:

> If clients encounter Too many connections errors when attempting to
>   connect to the MySQL server, all available connections are in use by
>   other clients.

I got resolved the issue after a few minutes, it seems that connection was been released by other clients, also I tried with restarting vs and workbench at same time.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by restarting the database windows service

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the real reason. Of course, restarting the DB will close all connections and start fresh, but if there are bugs in the OP's program, then those would cause the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

## Latest Solution

If you are using windows go to the following path :

```
‪C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
```

And add the below under the `[mysqld]` section :

```
max_connections = 500
```

Comment: It's not \data\, it's actually C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini