# C# MySql Connection "To many connections"

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I have some functions that connect to the database. For example : 
function with adds a new user after registration :

```
public void AddUser(UserModel user)
{
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into users (login , password , email ) values (@name , @password , @email)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", user.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", user.Password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", user.Email);         
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
}
```

I have more similar functions that invoke almost at the same time. 
When i run application I have a MySqlException : "Too many connections". 
I set max_connections to 100000 in my database and i set Pooling=false in connection string but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I would suggest wrapping `cmd` with `using`. Although to be honest I doubt that is the cause.

Comment: Are you sure that all other codes access the MySqlConnection inside a using statement?

Comment: there are other reasons you could get this error, including hardware related issues with space.  check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34176072/5463252

Comment: MySql use a fle with Extension .SDF.  There is no server so you can have issues when multi-users access the database.  It is better that you use a SQL Server which is designed for multi-users.  The SDF file has to be shared if more than one use is accessing the file (not a real database).

Comment: Mysql works just fine in multiuser situations and has a server also,I use it.that noted,try setting.i doubt your issue is to do with connection check the drive space,set global max_connection to 1000 works for me.stop server then start it.

Comment: Thanks for help, i will use SQL instead MySQL next time.