# DATABASE - Is phpMyAdmin.co down?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a project with a DB and whe are using phpMyAdmin.co for administration and I'm not able to connect with my DB administration (phpMyadmin) anymore (yesterday was the last time it worked).

I have tried to reach my host sql7 and phpMyadmin.co and they both didn't work. They where offline.

I've already looked here for the error "Too many connection" and they say I need to adjust something in my administration. But since I can't reach phpMyadmin It's not possible the do that.

Error: `Authentication to host 'sql7.freemysqlhosting.net' for user 'sql7269519' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Too many connections'`

Does anyone know if there are some issues with phpMyadmin.co or is there a problem with my code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14331032/9623582 see this if helps anyway.

Comment: @AbdurRahman I can't enter my database administration so it is not possible to adjust something.

Comment: You should contact your hosting providers for assistance. This looks like a resource limit that's in place to prevent too many simultaneous connections and if you don't have the administrative privileges to make changes, they'll have to help you through solving this problem.