# ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections error in node-express-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, aws-lambda

I have following setup,

**db.js**

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const config = require("../core/config/config.json");

const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: config.mysql.host,
    port: config.mysql.port,
    user: config.mysql.user,
    password: config.mysql.password
});

db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    connection.ping();
    connection.release();
    console.log("Database connected !");
});


module.exports = db;
```

Then I have many query files as shown below,

**query1.js**

```
const mysql = require("../db");

mysql.query("select * from table", [param], (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                return cb(error);
            }
            return cb(null, results);
});
```

**query2.js**

```
const mysql = require("../db");

mysql.query("select * from table", [param], (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                return cb(error);
            }
            return cb(null, results);
});
```

**query3.js**

```
const mysql = require("../db");

mysql.query("select * from table", [param], (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                return cb(error);
            }
            return cb(null, results);
});
```

and so on...

And I get

> ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections error in node-mysql

**When I deploy this code to AWS-lambda function. (Locally, it works fine).**

***What should I do it avoid above error with above setup ?***

**What am I doing wrong ?**

Comment: When do you encounter this error? I mean, immediately after the execution of the process or after a certain period? And is it part of a server?

Comment: After a certain period it happens but once it happens, it happens everytime. I have deployed my backend on aws-lamda function. Someone I want to close the connection after each query execution.

Comment: Try to use connection directly (.createConnection) instead of using connection pool.  Or only create connect(`db.getConnection` or `db.connect()`) in the lambda handler.

Comment: Did you release db connection after query ended?

Comment: Forget the older comment. I found that `pool.query()` do the releasing.

How about MySQL server's `max_connections` setting?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331032/mysql-error-1040-too-many-connection

Comment: By the way, there's [RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/) for database connection pooling with Lambda