# How to trace connections in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the classic `many connections` error in my MySQL app:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1129] Host 
'[IP ADDRESS]' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock 
with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'' in /var/www/libs/Database.php:15
```

There's plenty written on what causes this and how to solve it by increasing the limit, but what I haven't been able to determine is how to debug my code. I'd prefer to close the connection rather than have a load in use.

Is there any way to query MySQL to determine where connections are coming from and how long they have been open?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432241/mysql-show-status-active-or-total-connections Maybe this helps a bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I view live MySQL queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568564/how-can-i-view-live-mysql-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
show processlist
```

from the mysql cli this will show you the list of processes running, what commands they are running, and what IPs they are connected from.