# AWS RDS Mysql not responding after an alter query

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a AWS RDS MySQL 5.6.27 instance which was working perfectly fine. I did a alter on my table by executing this command.

```
ALTER TABLE images 
CHANGE `created_timestamp` `created_timestamp` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

After this I am unable to connect to this table at all. A select query on this table gives

> Error 2013 Lost connection to mysql.

I was able to query other tables.

How can I make it to work like before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The MySQL Error Log is [accessible from the RDS console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html).  Anything there?

Comment: check what is cpu utilization after that query , may be your process did no succeeded yet . Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432241/mysql-show-status-active-or-total-connections out

Comment: Having the same problem here.. Did you ever solve it?