# Confirm MySQL connection persistence for PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a PHP-based that uses MySQLi's connection persistence feature, but I'd like to fully confirm that it's working.

I expect that the information I need is somewhere in the results of the `mysqli_get_connection_stats($link)` function, or the corresponding MySQLND Statistics section available from `php_info()`, but I'm not really sure which values give me the information I need.

For example, I'm seeing values for `connection_reused`, does this indicate a persistent connection re-used, or a regular connection that hasn't timed out yet? `pconnect_success` is at 1, but I'm uncertain as `connect_success` is at 40, suggesting that there have been 39 non-persistent connections according to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.stats.php), but I'm unclear on why these may occur (as all scripts on the same host are using persistent connection methods).

One particular point of confusion is the `active_connections` stat which currently returns 18446744073709551578, I'm assuming it's overflowing somehow as that's close to the limit of a 64-bit integer, and I'm fairly certain I'm not maintaining quite so many connections!

I guess I'd just like to know how exactly I should read these stats in order to determine whether MySQLi is correctly using persistent connections or not.

Comment: persistent connections are almost always a bad idea

Comment: Care to elaborate? MySQLi's connection persistence performs automatic rollbacks, table unlocking etc., and the benefit in performance was noticeable on a previous host, I'm just not sure if they're still working as expected on my new one.

Comment: @Haravikk, Could you please add some more information about your new host's configuration: WEB-server, PHP version? Also, are you certain, that you did not observe such behavior on old host?

Comment: It looks like you are having 40 child PHP processes on new host, so each of them have its own persistent connection. But I can't say more certain without info about your host configuration. :( Take a look at a number of PHP processes run on your new host, - if it is equal 40 - thats' the reason of such a number of connections. ;)

Comment: Also, to get a number of connections to the DB, I would recomend you to run `show processlist;` on your MySQL server. Here are related quesitons with a little bit more info abobut this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432241/mysql-show-status-active-or-total-connections 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824428/number-of-db-connections-opened

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_ping()` or `mysqli::ping()` function to be sure the connection is alive. See http://php.net//manual/en/mysqli.ping.php

Comment: `mysqli_ping()` method does not confirm that persistent connection is working well.